# Криптография. Матрица Адамара. Вскрыть шифр. Почему неправильный ответ?

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы, криптография

Решаю задачу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на питоне набросал код, но ответ неправильный [8, 2, 4, 10, 3, 9, 1, 9, 10, 9, 8, 5].

Правильный: 8 2 3 7 6 4 4 3 9 7 0 3

`b` - элемент конечного поля (правильно ли это предположение?), и в `b_sq` содержатся значения `b^2mod(n-1)`.
Помогите понять, в чем ошибка? Спасибо
Использую модуль `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

b_sq = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9]
n = 12
A = [0] * (n-1)
for i in range(n-1):
    A[i] = [0] * (n-1)

for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(n-1):
        if (i == j):
            A[i][j] = 0
        elif ((i - j) % (n-1) in b_sq):
            A[i][j] = 1
        else:
            A[i][j] = -1

A_I = [0] * (n-1)                    #матрица A-I
for i in range(n-1):
    A_I[i] = [0] * (n-1)

for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(n-1):
        if (i==j):
            A_I[i][j] = A[i][j] - 1
        else:
            A_I[i][j] = A[i][j]

H = [0] * n
for i in range(n):
    H[i] = [0] * n

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if (i == 0 or j == 0):
            H[i][j] = 1
        else:
            H[i][j] = A_I[i - 1][j - 1]

x = np.array([10, 0, 6, -8, -2, 9, 6, 10, 3, -10, 7, 9])
k = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25])

R = np.array(H)

W = np.dot(x, R)      # промежуточный вектор-строка x*H

Result = [0] * n

for i in range(n):
    Result[i] = (W[i] + k[i]) % (n-1)

print(Result)
```

Comment: У меня когнитивный диссонанс с первой же матрицы в задании. Почему там A(n-1)*(n-1) и при этом нумерация в матрице начинается с 0 и получается n*n?

Comment: Правильный ответ получится если полученную вами матрицу транспонировать.

Comment: Проверил ваш код. Подумал что нашёл ошибку в использовании `NumPy`. Написал ответ. Нет, это не ошибка. Удалил ответ. Нашёл похожую [конструкцию Палея](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%8F). Но она только похожа, конструирует немного другую матрицу. Полностью переписал ваш код. Всё совпало с вами. Думаю, в задании опечатка. Например, матрица транспонированная. Или вектора-столбцы и последнее выражение `Hx + k`. Как-то так. Напишите чем всё закончилось. Интересно.

Comment: Спасибо, что навели не связь квадратичных вычетов с матрицами Адамара. Теория красивая. :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо большое за Ваш комментарий, к сожалению, вряд ли смогу узнать, в чем на самом деле проблема. эта задача из демоверсии олимпиады по крипто, где дан только ответ, так что спросить не у кого. думал, что, возможно, где-то я напортачил в решении. действительно, Ваши предположения выходят на правильный ответ